# Empty frames after using MediaCodec + MediaMuxer on Android

Tags: android, mp4

I'm trying to create .mp4 video from .png images in my app the next way:
decode Bitmap from .png file -> convert RGB bitmap to YUV420SP -> pass coverted bitmap to codec's input and queue it -> dequeue output frame -> write it with muxer to .mp4 file -> repeat with other image -> close and release muxer. The output .mp4 file cannot be played in Android but in VLC player it plays the right length (16 seconds at all, 4 sec with 4 images) but frames are empty, only VLC logo shown. I can't figure out what's wrong for few days, this last code is mix of few stackoverflow answers on similar questions, but I haven't found enough information to make it works.
Below the snippets

Here where all starts:

```
encoder = new AvcEncoder(this);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
byte[] data = getNV21(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap);
encoder.offerEncoder(data);
...
muxer.stop();
muxer.release();
```

This method is called from AvcEncoder when output appeared from codec:

```
@Override
public void frameReceived(byte[] outData, int i, int length) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(outData);

    bufferInfo.set(0, outData.length, duration * frameNo++ * 1000000, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME);
    muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, buf, bufferInfo);
}
```

Here converting snippets:

```
byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {

    int[] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

    scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

    byte[] yuv = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 / 2];
    encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

    scaled.recycle();

    return yuv;
}

void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    int yIndex = 0;
    int uvIndex = frameSize;

    int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
            R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

            // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
            Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
            U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
            //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
            //    pixel AND every other scanline.
            yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
            if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
            }

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

And *AvcEncoder* class:

```
public class AvcEncoder {

private EncodedFrameListener frameListener;
private MediaCodec mediaCodec;

private byte[] sps;
private byte[] pps;
//private ParameterSetsListener parameterSetsListener;

public AvcEncoder(EncodedFrameListener frameListener) {
    this.frameListener = frameListener;
    MediaFormat mediaFormat;
    mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 720, 720);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
    mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
    mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mediaCodec.start();

}


public MediaFormat getOutputFormat(){
    return mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
}
public void close() throws IOException {
    mediaCodec.stop();
    mediaCodec.release();
}

public void offerEncoder(byte[] input) {
    try {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(input);
            mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
        }

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, -1);
        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outputBuffer.get(outData);
            if (sps != null && pps != null) {
                ByteBuffer frameBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(outData);
                frameBuffer.putInt(bufferInfo.size - 4);
                frameListener.frameReceived(outData, 0, outData.length);
            } else {
                ByteBuffer spsPpsBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(outData);
                if (spsPpsBuffer.getInt() == 0x00000001) {
                    System.out.println("parsing sps/pps");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("something is amiss?");
                }
                int ppsIndex = 0;
                while(!(spsPpsBuffer.get() == 0x00 && spsPpsBuffer.get() == 0x00 && spsPpsBuffer.get() == 0x00 && spsPpsBuffer.get() == 0x01)) {

                }
                ppsIndex = spsPpsBuffer.position();
                sps = new byte[ppsIndex - 8];
                System.arraycopy(outData, 4, sps, 0, sps.length);
                pps = new byte[outData.length - ppsIndex];
                System.arraycopy(outData, ppsIndex, pps, 0, pps.length);
                /*if (null != parameterSetsListener) {
                    parameterSetsListener.avcParametersSetsEstablished(sps, pps);
                }*/
            }
            mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
            outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure that out? running into similar problems right now :(